# Como fazer pra mostrar o nome de todos os arrays dentro de um objeto?

Tags: javascript, array, objetos

Eu to fazendo um sistema de pesquisa e to com um problema para mostrar o nome dos arrays que tem dentro do objeto.

O objeto é nesse estilo:

```
let item = {
descricao: "Casa",
id: 123,
localizacoesFilho: [
    {
        descricao: "Cozinha",
        id: 124
    },
    {
        descricao: "Garagem",
        id: 125
    }
]
}
```

E o código que to usando é esse:

```
searchLocalizacao(item) {
  if (item.descricao) {

    if(item.localizacoesFilho && item.localizacoesFilho.length > 0) {
        return item.localizacoesFilho[0].descricao.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.q.toLowerCase()) == -1;
    }

    item.descricao.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.q.toLowerCase()) == -1;
  }
};
```

Esse código tá mostrando os itens que não tem um array normalmente, porém os itens que possuem array ele só mostra o nome se for o primeiro, como que eu faço para mostrar o nome do array que o usuário está pesquisando independente da posição dele?

Obs: o `this.q` está armazenando as letras que eu digito no input.

Answer (score 0):

O seu problema está aqui:

```
item.localizacoesFilho[0]
```

Você está pegando só o primeiro elemento do mesmo (0) e comparando, o que você precisa é iterar através todos os objetos dentro a `localizacoesFilho` e retornar aqueles que correspondem a sua condição, para fazer isso você pode usar métodos como o [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) que irá percorrer cada elemento do seu array e aplicar o teste que você definiu como parâmetro, tal método irá retornar um novo array com somente os objetos que passaram no teste predefinido, exemplo:

```
// Só para evitar de ter que converter para lowerCase em cada teste
const pesquisarPor = this.q.toLowerCase();

// Aplicamos um filtro no array, o teste é uma função que será chamada para cada elemento no array e deve retornar true ou false, se true o elemento será incluso no array filhosFiltrados
const filhosFiltrados = item.localizacoesFilho.filter(function(itemFilho){
   return itemFilho.descricao.toLowerCase().indexOf(pesquisarPor) > -1;
});
```

Exemplo simples:

```js
const item = {
  descricao: "Casa",
  id: 123,
  localizacoesFilho: [
      {
          descricao: "Cozinha",
          id: 124
      },
      {
          descricao: "Garagem",
          id: 125
      }
  ]
}


function searchLocalizacao(localizacao){
  const filhosFiltrados = item.localizacoesFilho.filter(function (filhoItem){
     return filhoItem.descricao.toLowerCase().indexOf(localizacao.toLowerCase()) > -1;
  });
  
  console.log(filhosFiltrados);
  return filhosFiltrados;
}

searchLocalizacao('a'); // Cozinha e Garagem
searchLocalizacao('G'); // Garagem
searchLocalizacao('oz'); // Cozinha
```

Comment: Leo, o código que você passou não deu nenhum problema, porém, do jeito que eu coloquei o código ta fazendo com que mostre os elementos que tem filho independentemente do que eu digite. Por exemplo, se eu digito Administração e o elemento que tem filho se chama Refeitório, fica mostrando a Administração e o Refeitório. Não consigo colocar o código aqui, então coloquei ele no JSFiddle: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/ve7qh0nk/)

Obs: eu já tentei deixar apenas o seu código, porém ele some todos os outros elementos da tela e deixa apenas os que tem filhos.
Obrigado, desde já.

Comment: Intanto podemos partir do começo, se a sua função deve retornar um `array` faça-a retornar um `array` sempre, tente ao máximo possível não misturar tipos de retorno pois isso pode ser uma dor de cabeça desnecessária, então caso a sua o seu array não tenha nenhum elemento não faça `return item.descricao.toLowerCase().indexOf(pesquisarPor) == -1` mas faça `return []` desta maneira será sempre um array vazio ou com elementos.

Comment: Pelo problema de mostrar ou não outros elementos no HTML, me parece ser um problema para outra pergunta, o escopo desta era filtrar os elementos dentro ao array e retornar os elementos que passam em um dado teste, e este me parece ser resolvido, se você quer saber o por quê de outros problemas é melhor fazer uma outra pergunta colocando o código que você está usando e explicar o problema em detalhes